# Alignment of text field and text area from Bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how to align my text fields and my text area. There is a slight difference in height

[image]

As you can see in the picture. The Phone number text field extends past the text area height a bit.My HTML has Ruby on Rails syntax in there but to apply classes, simply add the class name in `class:`. My HTML uses all the css provided by twitter bootstrap. I tried changing the rows but it it tends to extend too far

HTML:

```
<%= form_for(:contact, remote: true, class: "contact-input") do |f| %>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field(:last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last name") %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.email_field(:email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.telephone_field(:phone_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone number") %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_area(:message, class: "form-control", rows: "8", placeholder: "Message...") %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-xl") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The height for the text area depends on the number of rows.

So this can be done by reducing the margin of the text fields a little bit using a custom CSS class

```
.newMargin{
    margin-bottom:13px !important;
}
```

Check the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e75koy26/2/)**